# Is there a way in the Windows 10 registry (or otherwise) to suppress the "This function has been disabled by your administrator" message?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

On a Windows 10 machine located on a closed network which has been locked down in various ways through local GPO settings, there is a certain web application used with this machine that prompts a user to upload a local file.

On one pre-set user account this machine has had access to all but one drive restricted through a couple of GPO settings which I can't quite remember offhand ("Hide these specified drives" and another for allowing the one authorized drive "Permit this drive" or something like that).

The problem is that when used, this web application is apparently trying to gain access to the drives that are restricted on that account, so when a user uses that function, they get an error message saying something like "This function has been disabled by your administrator." After clicking through a few of those it works as expected with the one remaining allowed drive.

What I'm trying to do is just suppress those errors so the user doesn't see them and it goes right to where it should after clicking through them. It's okay if all such errors are suppressed for this user - as long as they stop appearing for this, I consider it successfully resolved.

Fixing the web application is not an option in the short term for this so it's something that needs to be doable through local-only GPO or registry settings (there's no domain controller or anything else involved), and applicable to only the specific local user account.

I couldn't find a GPO that covered this so I think the answer must be in the registry, if there is a way at all.

Comment: Either allow access (disable the GPO) or alter the program so it doesn't search there. The error itself cannot be avoided, so either it triggers or it doesn't. Its up to you to decide how to not trigger the error. So in your case, you probably want to change the default folder that is being opened.

Comment: I would agree.  You either give the user (read) access to the drive the application wants to attempt to access or you modify the application to no longer access the folder.  The error you are receiving is a result of the group polcy being configured.

Comment: Contact your IT department for a solution

Comment: @Moab context indicates he IS the IT department.

Comment: Can you modify the web app to set a default first location for where the File dialog loads? I know you can specify this in local apps. Basically, fix the system that is calling the thing that causes the error.